# dotnet core autofac and json configuration can they all work together in a console app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I have been trying to get some `dependency injection` into my `.net` core console app as well as use an `appsettings.json file`.

However I can't find an example with both together.

Below is a method I have to set this up from inside my `Main()`

```
private static IContainer SetupDependencyInjection()
{
        var builder2 = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(
            typeof(Program).GetTypeInfo().Assembly // Console
        )
        .AsSelf()
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var container = builder.Build();

        return container;
    }
```

You can see I have the builder2 variable to set up the config file but then I need the builder variable for the Dependency Injection.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Did you read this? http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html

Comment: Also note this statement in the documentation: "JSON or XML is recommended when concrete classes cannot be chosen or configured at compile-time.".

Comment: Probably you can get a solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47168907

Answer (score 4):

*Autofac* provides a `ConfigurationModule` class that can be build using a `Iconfiguration` provided by your `ConfigurationBuilder`

```
// Add the configuration to the ConfigurationBuilder.
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");

// Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(module);

// configure whatever you want at runtime the ContainerBuilder
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<IFoo>(); 

// build the container 
IContainer container = builder.Build();
```

In this case you will have both registrations configured in your *autofac.json* file and registrations configured in your code.

See [Autofac documentation JSON/XML Configuration](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html) for more detail

Comment: Thanks @Cyril.  One question.  autofac.json I don't quite know what I am doing with that file as I am happy to have all the registrations inline.  But where does my application.json belong?  The autofac.json looks like it only contains the autofac code and not application variables.

Comment: If you are happy to have all the registrations inline why do you want to use the json configuration file ? it is an optional feature and *Autofac* doesn't need it. If you don't want it, don't configure the `ConfigurationModule` module :)

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained in the question more my apologies.  I have no desire to put the autofac config in json but I want to use the appsettings.json (which is the application settings).  Much like the web.config.  I have seen examples of the appsettings.json being used and strongly typed etc. but not when dependency injection is also being used.  I am sure it is possible but I am just missing the link in code.