# ConfigurationModule passed into Module and context - DotNet Core

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-module, autofac-configuration

So I'm trying to use Autofac DI to pass my configuration json file through the stack. My Main function is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Starting...");

        // Add the configuration to the ConfigurationBuilder.
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register the ConfigurationModule with Autofac.
        var configurationModule = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());

        containerBuilder.RegisterModule(configurationModule);
        // register a specific consumer
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<BusSettings>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<BusModule>();

        Container = containerBuilder.Build();
}
```

I have sucessfully registered the modules here... next my BusModule is loaded...

```
public class BusModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(context =>
            {
                // Load the settings from the the busSettings class, which entail should come from the config file...
                var busSettings = context.Resolve<BusSettings>();

                var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(busSettings.HostAddress, h =>
                    {
                        h.Username(busSettings.Username);
                        h.Password(busSettings.Password);
                    });
                });
                busControl.Start();
                return busControl;
            })
            .SingleInstance().AutoActivate().As<IBusControl>().As<IBus>();
    }
}
```

My BusSettings class is then resolved but this is where I want the config file to be used to set up the properties, the issue is I don't know how to access the config file from there...

```
 public class BusSettings
{
    // I want to be able to get the values from here:
    // But how do I access the config file declared in Main()??
    var hostAddress = _config["AppSettings:HostAddress"];

    //connecting to default vhost
    public Uri HostAddress { get; } = new Uri(hostAddress);

    //using default rabbitmq administrative user
    public string Username { get; } = // Get config from file... ;

    //using default rabbitmq administrative user password
    public string Password { get; } = "";

    public string QueueName { get; } = "";

    //using IIS Express Development Certificate that has cn=localhost
    public string SslServerName { get; } = "";
}
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to register `configBuilder.Build()` as `IConfiguration` with Autofac and you're good to go.  So it would look something like the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configBuilder
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var config = configBuilder.Build();

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.Register(context => config).As<IConfiguration>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<BusSettings>();
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();

        var busSettings = container.Resolve<BusSettings>();

        Console.WriteLine(busSettings.HostAddress.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

With the BusSettings class implemented like this:

```
public class BusSettings 
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public BusSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public Uri HostAddress => new Uri(_configuration["AppSettings:HostAddress"]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the right solution, I ended up using the in built IServiceCollection object and calling services.Configure<BusSettings>(configuration.GetSection("Configuration")); and then    services.AddSingleton(configuration); however this approach is cleaner. I do find it weird that the RegisterModule(ConfigurationModule) pretty much does nothing then!

Comment: Finally some sense! This is the key: `containerBuilder.Register(context => config).As<IConfiguration>();`. I've been going absolutely nuts trying to follow the official docs (and other SO posts / blogs) all saying to use `RegisterModule()` but it doesn't work. I think the penny has dropped that using `RegisterModule(new ConfigurationModule(config.Build()))` is specifically for Autofac configuration, *NOT* application configuration. As such, it does nothing to allow you to access the underlying `IConfiguration` object. The docs are awful and don't spell this out in any way.